# Try to use pipe to replace for-loop (results are not the same)

Tags: r

I am trying to use pipe to replace a for-loop (the overall for-loop would take over hours).

This is how my data sample (DF) look like (for one case):

```
CaseNumber  Hour  Total   
A000123      1     125      
A000123     10     125   
A000123     12     125   
A000123     58     125   
A000123     79     125
```

Here is the original code for one case (note: the original data already sorted by "Hour"):

```
ns= 125/nrow(DF) 
Total = 125
DF$Order = rep(ns,nrow(DF))
DF$Order = cumsum(DF$Order)-ns

DF$ModifyOrder = rep(1,nrow(DF))
DF$Change= rep(1,nrow(DF)) 

for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){
  if(i ==1){
    DF$Change[i] = (Total -0+1)/(Total -DF$Order[i]+1)
    DF$ModifyOrder[i]= 0+1*DF$Change[i]
  }else{
    DF$Change[i] = (Total -DF$ModifyOrder[i-1]+1)/(Total -DF$Order[i]+1)
    DF$ModifyOrder[i]= DF$ModifyOrder[i-1]+1*DF$Change[i]
  }  
}
```

Since I have hundreds of thousands of Cases (the data structure looks like the data sample RawDF showing below), I tried to use pipe instead.

```
CaseNumber  Hour  Total   
A000123      1     125      
A000123     10     125   
A000123     12     125   
A000123     58     125   
A000123     79     125   
B0XD127     50     5897
B0XD127     58     5897
B0XD127    121     5897
B0XD127    279     5897
B0XD127    287     5897
B0XD127    304     5897
B0XD127    515     5897
AKB48       11     1280 
AKB48       11     1280 
AKB48       12     1280 
AKB48       57     1280 
AKB48       59     1280 
AKB48       75     1280
```

Here's my pipe code:

```
RawDF = RawDF %>% group_by(CaseNumber) %>% 
  mutate(Sample = n()) %>% 
  mutate(ns = Total /Sample ) %>% 
  arrange(Hour) %>% 
  mutate(Order= cumsum(ns)-ns ) %>% ungroup()

RawDF$Change = rep(0,nrow(RawDF ))
RawDF$ModifyOrder = rep(0,nrow(RawDF))

RawDF = RawDF %>% group_by(CaseNumber) %>% 
  arrange(Hour) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Change=  (Total +1-lag(ModifyOrder,default = 0, order_by = Hour))/(Total +1-Order),
                ModifyOrder = cumsum(Change) )
```

The results are close but not the same. For example, if the original for loop gives me 6.1879 for one of the "Order", then the corresponding "Order" calculated by pipe could be 6.1768. Similar but not the same and means it's not correct.

This really bothers me a lot. I would like to know which part is going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are `arrange`ing in your pipe but there is no `sort`, `rank`, or `order` in your initial implementation. Also, your `for` implementation has no concept of groups, so your calculations are wrong there.

Comment: @r2evans , the original data already sort the hour (note: hour is the only thing need to be sorted). But I sort hour in pipe by using "arrange". The final results between the original for-loop and the pipe are very close but not the same. If the original Order is 6.1879 then the pipe gives me 6.1459 (something like that). I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Whenever grouping is involved, I tend to favor `dplyr` or `data.table` implementations. While R does do grouping stuff (and can do it well and fast), I feel it is not always as intuitive, and that can translate into readability, verifiability, etc. Whenever I see base R code that works on data that needs to be grouped, I usually cringe, as relying on the "Excel model of grouping" (e.g., if this row's group is different from last row's group) has so many efficiency if not correctness problems.

Comment: For this question, I suggest you focus on the `dplyr` pipe and verify your numbers. Prioritize verified-correct methodology over base-R versus external-package. Prioritize readability and maintainability over compactness. (In my opinion, always. "Clever" and "compact" are not always better, even if they are perhaps faster execution.)

Comment: I notice the problem is "lag". It didn't renew ModifyOrder and always use "0" in that equation. However, I tried to add n = 1 into lag and the results are just worse. :(

Comment: There's not as much that we can help with until this question becomes a little more self-contained and such. For instance, are the 18 rows you included sufficient to represent what you're looking at? Most importantly, though, do you know what the answer should be for a given *small* set of data? It's even more difficult to say which is better (base or pipe) without know which if any of your code produces correct answers.